# Quisiera rellenar otros textbox con evento leave

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Buenas tardes mi idea es que haga una condición ejemplo
if (textbox1.text !="") - lo busque en la base de datos si hay datos que me los traiga y
rellene los otros textbox...n con los datos de los otros campos de la base de datos

Comment: Lectura recomendadísima: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: quiero que con el evento textbox_leave me haga una condicion de que si existe me rellene los otros text box con los datos que le corresponden de cada campo

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Y cual es el problema? porque ahi solo describis lo que tenes que hacer....